# CSS curve wave background

Tags: html, css, curve, wave

I am a new learner of  html and css.  I want to make my circle orange background curve wave using only css not using background-image or svg. Like the screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDQeY.png
[image]

Without using background image curve just css in (.circle-inner). But I am failed to making this. I am tried a lot. I upload my html and css code.

My html and css code:

```css
.circle-inner {
    width: 310px;
    height: 310px;
 background-color:#d1132f;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 100%;
 border: 1px solid #ff8403;
 display:table;
 position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.circle-points {
    display:  table-cell;
    vertical-align:  middle;
    margin:  0 auto;
    text-align:  center;
 color: #fff;
}
.circle-points h2 {
    margin:  0;
    font-size: 68px;
}

.circle-points span {
    display:  block;
    font-size: 26px;
}

/* if circle reset */
.circle-inner:after {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    content: '';
    z-index: -1;
 
    background: #ffc815; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #ffc815 0%, #ff7e01 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ffc815 0%,#ff7e01 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffc815 0%,#ff7e01 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffc815', endColorstr='#ff7e01',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */     
}

/* if point 1 */
.circle-inner:after {
    /* background-color:orange; */
    top: 60%;     
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-area">
    <div class="circle-inner">
        <div class="circle-points">
            <h2>1</h2><span>Point</span>
        </div>         
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This might help - http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor

Comment: @Saharsh I want the curve or wave like this:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDQeY.png

Comment: Why not go for an SVG ?

Comment: An SVG can be easily embedded in your HTML, it is XML in the end, and it would give you the level of customization you need here.

Comment: @rach8garg is ti not possible in css?

Comment: @Andry is ti not possible in css?

Comment: The curving is what bothers me a little. Probably you can, maybe. But it is gonna be a complex structure in the end. If you do this in SVG it is going to be a few lines. In pure CSS you will end up with more stuff, not easy to maintain in the future. In my opinion, going for SVG fits better your scenario. Why do you think we have SVG? You are trying to create a piece of complex graphics...

Comment: @Andry  Because I will fill the circle with the orange color with the points condition in js. So, in js condition I will add the css class to up/down the orange background.

Comment: There is no possibility to do it with CSS. Not at all.

Comment: It's not really impossible to achieve the curves in CSS but it will be very complex and/or may not be responsive. SVG is a better pick in this case.

Comment: @Saharsh I got svg and with background-image. I need in pure css if complex no problem.No need responsive.

Comment: @SharwarAmanSymon: You are trying to do one thing can could be achieved simply with one technology, SVG, by using a more complex solution employing 3 technologies: HTML, CSS and Javascript.

Comment: I tried my best with SVG, if you want to use it sometime. [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ftgmth7d/).

Comment: Never Say Never lol. It can be done in just CSS. Check my answer.

Answer (score 8):

I used Div Containers and CSS to reproduce your required results. Feel free to tweak as you need.  First i made a div container with a border or 50% on all sides for our circle.  Next i built 2 more divs with a border radius and gradient and rotated them to place to create the results. Hope it helps.

```css
.circleContainer{
width:400px;
height:400px;
border-radius:50%;
background-color:#ffcc33;
margin-left:30%;
margin-top:5%;
position:absolute;
overflow:hidden;
transform:rotate(17deg);
}
.splitA{
width:100%;
height:40%;
float:left;
background-color:#cc0066;
}
.curveOne{
width:100%;
position:absolute;
height:60%;
float:left;
transform:rotate(-50deg);
margin-left:-13%;
margin-top:-7%;
border-bottom-left-radius:60%;
border-top-left-radius:0%;
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red,  #cc0066); 
}
.curveTwo{
width:100%;
position:absolute;
height:60%;
float:left;
margin-left:20%;
margin-top:45%;
transform:rotate(-50deg);
border-bottom-right-radius:0%;
border-top-right-radius:40%;
background: linear-gradient(to top, #cc6600, #ff9933, #ffcc33); 
}
```

```html
<div class="circleContainer">
<div class="splitA"><div class="curveOne"></div></div>
<div class="curveTwo"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: it looks good but Not as that I want.  Because in my code there is class " .circle-inner:after " . I want the curve only top in this class. because I will up down that with %. using top.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```css
#yin-yang {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 80vmin;
  height: 80vmin;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(black 50%, #3ed89c 0);
}
#yin-yang:before, #yin-yang:after {
  flex: 1;
  height: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: black;
  content: "";
}
#yin-yang:after { 
  background: #3ed89c;
}
```

```html
<div id="yin-yang"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the example below.

You can take help of SVG Cubic Bezier curves to create complex shapes. You need to specify three sets of coordinates.

> C x1 y1, x2 y2, x y (or c dx1 dy1, dx2 dy2, dx dy)

Check this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths

```html
<svg width="190" height="160" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M10 80 C 40 10, 65 10, 95 80 S 150 150, 180 80" stroke="black" fill="transparent"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: No svg or background image. I need only css

Comment: Not sure why do you need to be rigid about it.
You can try and discover a new way then. Let the whole developer community know if you are able to achieve that with current CSS standards. Good luck.